# Vue not compiling right

Tags: vue.js, axios

Im trying to develop something easy, list somethings in a external JSON 
https://api.myjson.com/bins/qs4ao

Github link: https://github.com/brunomosciatti/gc

But the code randomly works... Sometimes nothing copiles, but if I break something in html like remove an end tag (eg: ) and forces to generate the error message, after that I fix this ending tag and then the pages compiles alright.

Furthermore, some part of my json is not getting visible by my code.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <main class="container player-content">
      <p style="background:red;color:#fff;">{{gc.games.title}}></p>
      <p style="background:red;color:#fff;">{{gc.games.cta}}</p>


      <div class="col-xs-12 noPadd player-header">
        <div class="col-xs-3 player-avatar">
          <img src="/src/assets/images/avatar.png" width="40px" title="gc.user.name" />
          <h3>{{gc.user.name}}</h3>
          <h4>GC ID: {{gc.user.id}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 player-progress">
          <span class="casual">casual <img src="/src/assets/images/pin.svg"/></span>
          <span class="amador">amador <img src="/src/assets/images/pin.svg"/></span>
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45"
            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:45%">
              <span class="sr-only">45% alcançado</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span class="comp">competitivo <img src="/src/assets/images/pin.svg"/></span>
          <span class="pro">pro <img src="/src/assets/images/pin.svg"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="player-badges noPadd col-xs-2">
          <ul>
            <li><img title="Iniciante" src="/src/assets/images/beginner.svg" width="40px"/></li>
            <li><img width="29px" style="margin-top:3px;" v-bind:src="gc.user.patent" /></li>
            <li><img v-bind:title="gc.user.featured_medal.title" width="29px" style="margin-top:3px; margin-left:5px" v-bind:src="gc.user.featured_medal.image" /></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="player-patent col-xs-1 noPadd">
          <img title="Ouro 2" src="/src/assets/images/patent.png" width="55px"/>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row col-xs-12 row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-xs-6 sv4fun">
          <span>
            <img v-bind:title="gc.forfun.title" v-bind:src="gc.forfun.image" width="28px;" />
            <p>4 FUN</p>
          </span>
          <div class="noPadd sv-card">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="" title="Copiar IP"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="" title="Entrar no servidor"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <span class="sv-name">#133 - Deathmatch</span>
            <span class="sv-mode">DM FFA</span>
            <span class="sv-map">de_overpass <em>08/16</em></span>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50"
              aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
                <span class="sr-only">50% ocupado</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="noPadd sv-card">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="" title="Copiar IP"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="" title="Entrar no servidor"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <span class="sv-name">#133 - Deathmatch</span>
            <span class="sv-mode">DM FFA</span>
            <span class="sv-map">de_overpass <em>08/16</em></span>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50"
              aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
                <span class="sr-only">50% ocupado</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="noPadd sv-card">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="" title="Copiar IP"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="" title="Entrar no servidor"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <span class="sv-name">#133 - Deathmatch</span>
            <span class="sv-mode">DM FFA</span>
            <span class="sv-map">de_overpass <em>08/16</em></span>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50"
              aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
                <span class="sr-only">50% ocupado</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 lobby">
          <span><img title="LOBBY" src="/src/assets/images/lobby.svg" width="20px"/><p>LOBBY</p></span>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="partidas">1564</h3>
            <h4>partidas</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="vitorias">1100</h3>
            <h4>vitórias</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="derrotas">464</h3>
            <h4>derrotas</h4>
          </div>
          <a href="#" title="Ir para o lobby">IR PARA LOBBY</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 ranked">
          <span><img title="RANKED OPEN" src="/src/assets/images/Open.svg" width="20px"/><p>RANKED OPEN</p></span>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="partidasRanked">1564</h3>
            <h4 >partidas</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="vitorias">1100</h3>
            <h4 >vitórias</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="derrotas">464</h3>
            <h4 >derrotas</h4>
          </div>
          <a href="#" title="Ir para o lobby"><em><i class="fas fa-users"></i> 15</em> entrar na fila</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 noPadd footer">
          <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-download"></i>Download Gamers Club Anti-Cheat</a>
          <div class="gc-info">
            <span>{{gc.online}}</span> <p>Jogadores<em>Online</em></p>
            <div class="ban"><span>{{gc.latest_banned}}</span> <p>Cheaters Banidos<em>Nos Últimos 7 dias</em></p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
 name: 'app',
 data () {
   return {
     online: '',
     name: '',

     user: {
       name: '',
       id: '',
       expertise : '',
       is_subscriber : '',
       patent : '',
       level : '',
       game_position: {
         id: '',
         title: '',
         image: ''
       },
       featured_medal: {
         id: '',
         title: '',
         image: ''
       }
     },

     games: {
       title: '',
       cta: {
         title : '',
         link : '',
       }
     },



   }
 },
 mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/qs4ao')
      .then(response => {
        this.gc = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)
  }
}

</script>

<style>
body {
 margin: 0;
}

#app {
 font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 color: #2c3e50;
}

main {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 40px;
}

header {
 margin: 0;
 height: 56px;
 padding: 0 16px 0 24px;
 background-color: #35495E;
 color: #ffffff;
}

header span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 1;
 letter-spacing: .02em;
 font-weight: 400;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-top: 16px;
}


button {
 background: #51B767;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 15px;
 border: 0;
}

.cards {
 background: #F5F5F5;
 height:400px;
}
.cards:hover {
 transform: translateY(-0.5em);
 background: #EBEBEB;
}


.cards {
  column-count: 1;
 column-gap: 1em;
   margin-top: 70px;

}
</style>
```

I expect to list everything from the JSON

Comment: Sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/mmynv8pj3x

Answer (score 0):

`gc` is not defined in your `data` object. You need to have a blank `gc` object like below. Vue is computing before mounting and is needing data. Your codesandbox has the console error `Property or method "gc" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

```
data () {
   return {
     ...
     games: {
       title: '',
       cta: {
         title : '',
         link : '',
       }
     },
     gc: {} // add this
   }
 },
```

Comment: Still the same, bro.. Did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated like @Varcorb told and its getting better.

But I cant list "gc.forfun.servers.title" ; "gc.games.title" and others...

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <main class="container player-content">
      <div class="col-xs-12 noPadd player-header">
        <div class="col-xs-3 player-avatar">
          <img
            src="/src/assets/images/avatar.png"
            width="40px"
            title="gc.user.name"
          />
          <h3>{{ gc.user.name }}</h3>
          <h4>GC ID: {{ gc.user.id }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 player-progress">
          <span class="casual">casual <img src="/src/assets/images/pin.svg"/></span>
          <span class="amador">amador <img src="/src/assets/images/pin.svg"/></span>
          <div class="progress">
            <div
              class="progress-bar"
              role="progressbar"
              aria-valuenow="45"
              aria-valuemin="0"
              aria-valuemax="100"
              style="width:45%"
            >
              <span class="sr-only">45% alcançado</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span class="comp">competitivo <img src="/src/assets/images/pin.svg"
          /></span>
          <span class="pro">pro <img src="/src/assets/images/pin.svg"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="player-badges noPadd col-xs-2">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img
                title="Iniciante"
                src="/src/assets/images/beginner.svg"
                width="40px"
              />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img
                width="29px"
                style="margin-top:3px;"
                v-bind:src="gc.user.patent"
              />
            </li>
            <li>
              <img
                v-bind:title="gc.user.featured_medal.title"
                width="29px"
                style="margin-top:3px; margin-left:5px"
                v-bind:src="gc.user.featured_medal.image"
              />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="player-patent col-xs-1 noPadd">
          <img
            title="Ouro 2"
            src="/src/assets/images/patent.png"
            width="55px"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row col-xs-12 row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-xs-6 sv4fun">
          <span>
            <img
              v-bind:title="gc.forfun.title"
              v-bind:src="gc.forfun.image"
              width="28px;"
            />
            <p>4 FUN</p>
          </span>
          <div class="noPadd sv-card">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="" title="Copiar IP"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" title="Entrar no servidor"
                  ><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i
                ></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="sv-name">#133 - Deathmatch</span>
            <span class="sv-mode">DM FFA</span>
            <span class="sv-map">de_overpass <em>08/16</em></span>
            <div class="progress">
              <div
                class="progress-bar"
                role="progressbar"
                aria-valuenow="50"
                aria-valuemin="0"
                aria-valuemax="100"
                style="width:50%"
              >
                <span class="sr-only">50% ocupado</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="noPadd sv-card">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="" title="Copiar IP"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" title="Entrar no servidor"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="sv-name">#133 - Deathmatch</span>
            <span class="sv-mode">DM FFA</span>
            <span class="sv-map">de_overpass <em>08/16</em></span>
            <div class="progress">
              <div
                class="progress-bar"
                role="progressbar"
                aria-valuenow="50"
                aria-valuemin="0"
                aria-valuemax="100"
                style="width:50%"
              >
                <span class="sr-only">50% ocupado</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="noPadd sv-card">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="" title="Copiar IP"><i class="far fa-copy"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="" title="Entrar no servidor"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="sv-name">#133 - Deathmatch</span>
            <span class="sv-mode">DM FFA</span>
            <span class="sv-map">de_overpass <em>08/16</em></span>
            <div class="progress">
              <div
                class="progress-bar"
                role="progressbar"
                aria-valuenow="50"
                aria-valuemin="0"
                aria-valuemax="100"
                style="width:50%"
              >
                <span class="sr-only">50% ocupado</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 lobby">
          <span
            ><img
              title="LOBBY"
              src="/src/assets/images/lobby.svg"
              width="20px"
            />
            <p>LOBBY</p></span
          >
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="partidas">1564</h3>
            <h4>partidas</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="vitorias">1100</h3>
            <h4>vitórias</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="derrotas">464</h3>
            <h4>derrotas</h4>
          </div>
          <a href="#" title="Ir para o lobby">IR PARA LOBBY</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 ranked">
          <span
            ><img
              title="RANKED OPEN"
              src="/src/assets/images/Open.svg"
              width="20px"
            />
            <p>RANKED OPEN</p></span
          >
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="partidasRanked">1564</h3>
            <h4>partidas</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="vitorias">1100</h3>
            <h4>vitórias</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-stats col-md-4">
            <h3 class="derrotas">464</h3>
            <h4>derrotas</h4>
          </div>
          <a href="#" title="Ir para o lobby"
            ><em><i class="fas fa-users"></i> 15</em> entrar na fila</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 noPadd footer">
          <a href="#"
            ><i class="fas fa-download"></i>Download Gamers Club Anti-Cheat</a>
          <div class="gc-info">
            <span>{{ gc.online }}</span>
            <p>Jogadores<em>Online</em></p>
            <div class="ban">
              <span>{{ gc.latest_banned }}</span>
              <p>Cheaters Banidqos<em>Nos Últimos 7 dias</em></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    gc: {
    }
    return {
      online: "",
      name: {},
      gc: {},

      user: {
        name: "",
        id: "",
        expertise: "",
        is_subscriber: "",
        patent: "",
        level: "",
        game_position: {
          id: "",
          title: "",
          image: ""
        },
        featured_medal: {
          id: "",
          title: "",
          image: ""
        }
      },

      games: {
        title: "",
        cta: {
          title: "",
          link: ""
        }
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/qs4ao")
      .then(response => {
        this.gc = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errored = true;
      })
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
  }
};
</script>
```